# Assertion error in LWFBrook90 run over than Maxiter

Tags: model, simulation, assertion

Hi I am using LWFBrook 90 v1.9 to simulate the hydro-dynamics. These are the scripts I am using:

```
using LWFBrook90

model1 = loadSPAC(input_path, input_prefix; simulate_isotopes = false);
simulation = setup(model1)
simulate!(simulation)
```

Here are the data I am using. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1n_DFlr83QLa1bwmMjsiOAHRaRgErXvb-?usp=drive_link

However, I have this error.

ERROR: AssertionError: Problem with simulation: Return code of simulation was ‘MaxIters’
Stacktrace: [1] simulate!(s::DiscretizedSPAC; assert_retcode::Bool, kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})

I am thinking to increase the Maxiters, but I don’t know how to use:

```
using OrdinaryDiffEq: solve
solve(simulation, maxiters = 1e7, progress = true)
```

ERROR: MethodError: no method matching init(::DiscretizedSPAC; maxiters::Float64, progress::Bool, save_idxs::Vector{Int64})

Closest candidates are:
init(::Roots.ZeroProblem) got unsupported keyword arguments "maxiters", "progress", "save_idxs"
Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!